# Parsing through string of integers in Python

Tags: python

[Runes expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nefE.png)
Hey guys so I really need help. Objective of the program is to have user input a number. This number will be converted to base 4 and the conversion will be used to draw a rune(character) that corresponds. I am having trouble handling the input and also how can I go about parsing through a string of ints, then printing the corresponding runes(characters) to the console. Right now I am testing in the test method but I plan on moving this to the main method. I have provided a screenshot of the expected input and my source code thus far.

Any help is appreciated.

-Thanks

```
{"""
file: runes.py
language: python3
description: translate numbers to base 4 runes, displayed by turtle
"""

# In-Lab: Expand lines marked with asterisks ("****")
#         You may have to ignore much of the documentation.

# When implementing the complete lab,
# refer to the posted pydoc file for details.

import math
import turtle

# The following is handy for debugging.
DEBUG = False   # If true, print extra information during execution.

# The user prompt
PROMPT = "0 to exit> "

# Some constants that keep you from recomputing things while drawing.
# The first few can be changed to modify the runes' shapes.

RUNE_HEIGHT = 20
RUNE_WIDTH = 10
RUNE_SPACING = 5
HALF_RUNE_HEIGHT = RUNE_HEIGHT / 2
QUARTER_RUNE_HEIGHT = RUNE_HEIGHT / 4

QUARTER_TURN = 90
EIGHTH_TURN = QUARTER_TURN // 2
TWELFTH_TURN = QUARTER_TURN // 3
SIN_EIGHTH_TURN = math.sin( math.radians( EIGHTH_TURN ) )
SIN_TWELFTH_TURN = math.sin( math.radians( TWELFTH_TURN ) )
COS_TWELFTH_TURN = math.cos( math.radians( TWELFTH_TURN ) )


def to_base( num, radix ):
    """
    Convert an integer to a different base.
    :param num: the int to be represented in some base
    :param radix: the integer base
    :return: a sequence of integers or integer characters representing the
             coefficients, or digit values, LEAST significant digit first, of
             the integer in the specified base. There will be no leading zeros
             at the end of the sequence.
    :pre: num > 0
    """
    s = ""
    while num > 0:
        s = str(num % radix) + s
        num = num // radix

    return int(s)

def test_to_base():

    for base in 10, 4, 12:
        print( "Base", base )
        for n in tuple( range( 1, 14 ) ) + ( 57, 136 ):
            print( n, "-->", to_base( n, base ) )
        print()

def draw( n ):
    """
    Draw a single rune digit.
    :pre: Turtle is facing right.
    :pre: Turtle's pen is up.
    :pre: Turtle is at the bottom left of the rune to be drawn.
    :pre: n is greater than 0 and less than RADIX.
    :post: Turtle is facing right.
    :post: Turtle's pen is up.
    :post: Turtle is at the bottom left of the spot where the next rune
           would be drawn.
    :param n: a positive number of type int
    :return: NoneType
    """

    # ADDITIONAL CODE WILL BE NEEDED IN THIS FUNCTION FOR
    # THE FULL LAB ASSIGNMENT.
    if n == 3:
        turtle.right(-90)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(20)
        turtle.right(-60)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(60)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(90)
    elif n == 2:
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(-100, 0)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.right(-90)
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(-220)
        turtle.forward(130)
    elif n == 1:
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(60)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(95)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(95)
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.right(60)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(45)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(45)
        turtle.right(300)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(80)
        turtle.left(270)
    elif n == 0:
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.penup()
    else:
        assert False, str( n ) + " is out of range?"

def test( ):
    """
    :return: NoneType
    """

    # SOME OF THE LINES BELOW WILL BE USED IN main IN THE FULL LAB ASSIGNMENT.
    n = int((input('Input something:')))
    while n >= 0:
        turtle.setheading( 0 )
        test_to_base( )
        draw( n )
        turtle.done()

def main( ):
    """
    :return: NoneType
    """

    # FILL THIS IN FOR THE FULL LAB ASSIGNMENT.
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test( )
}
```

Comment: This is too broad. Try to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You shouldn't just dump code and ask for it to be fixed. This is not a programming tutoring/debugging service.

Comment: `def base10toN(num,n):
    return ((num == 0) and  "0" ) or ( base10toN(num // n, n).strip("0") + "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[:n][num % n])`
is this what you are looking for???

Answer (score 0):

```
def base10toN(num,n):
    return ((num == 0) and  "0" ) or ( base10toN(num // n, n).strip("0") + "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[:n][num % n])

try:
    number = input()
except:
    print("this is not a integer")
print(base10toN(number,4))
```

as op is tagged with python so adding python 2.7code